# non-broadcastable output operand numpy 2D cast into 3D

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy,

```
    foo = np.array([[i+10*j for i in range(10)] for j in range(3)])
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
    filter = np.nonzero(foo > 100)#nothing matches

    foo[:,filter]
    array([], shape=(3, 2, 0), dtype=int64)

    foo[:,0:0]
    array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=int64)

filter2 = np.nonzero(np.sum(foo,axis=0) < 47)
foo[:,filter2]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]])
foo[:,filter2].shape
(3, 1, 6)
```

I have a 'filter' condition where I want to perform an operation on all rows for all matching columns, but if filter is an empty array, somehow my foo[:,filter] gets broadcast into a 3D array. Another example is with filter2 -> again, foo[:,filter2] gives me a 3D array when I am expecting the result of foo[:,(np.sum(foo,axis=0) < 47)]

Can someone explain what the proper use case of np.nonzero is compared to using booleans to find the correct columns/indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `foo[filter] == foo[filter.nonzero()]` when `filter` is a Boolean array.

To understand why you're getting unexpected results you have to understand a little about how python does indexing. To do multidimensional indexing in python you can either use indices in `[]`, separated by commas or use a tuple. So `foo[1, 2, 3]` is the same as `foo[(1, 2, 3)]`. With this in mind take a look at what happens when you do `foo[:, something]`. I believe in your example you were trying to get `foo[:, something[0], something[1]]`, but instead you got `foo[(slice[None], (something[0], something[1]))]`.

This is all somewhat academic, because if you're just using `filter` for indexing you probably don't need to use nonzero, just use the boolean array as the index but if you need to, you can do something like:

```
foo[:, filter[0]]

# OR
index = (slice(None),) + filter.nonzero()
foo[index]
```